compute intensive function with multiple outputs applied elementwise to polars Array column, use iter_slices?
I need to apply a compute intensive function, mainly consisting of calls to numpy functions, to a column of a polars DataFrame that has the pl.Array(...) datatype. In need a streaming method, as my actual data is regularly larger than the computer memory. I can do it using iter_slices, creating DataFrames, and concatenating them.
But it really feels like this is something map_batches is meant to be used for, but it doesn't handle multiple return values. Is there something else I should look at, or should I call this good enough until I implement a rust UDF?
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

filter1 = np.array([-1,1,-1,1,1])
filter2 = np.array([0.3,0.3,-0.3,0.3, 0.3])

def compute(x):
    a = np.dot(x, filter1)
    b = np.dot(x, filter2)
    return np.sin(a-b), np.cos(a+b)

df = pl.DataFrame({"a":[np.arange(5.0)+i for i in range(5)]}, schema={"a":pl.Array(pl.Float64,5)})

dfs = []
for df_iter in df.iter_slices(10000):
    peak_x, peak_y = compute(df_iter["a"].to_numpy())
    dfs.append(pl.DataFrame({"c": peak_x, "d": peak_y}))
df_out = pl.concat(dfs)


You can return pl.select(c=np.sin(a-b), d=np.cos(a+b)).to_struct() for map_batches and unnest the fields. But can't you just call pl.DataFrame(compute(df['a']))?

I forgot to mention that I need to do this in a streaming compatible way because I can't load all of df['a'] into memory with my actual data. Edited question to note that.
